# AXIS2 How to set connection retry?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-axis

It seems that the Axis admin client org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient 
is issuing org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry() and 
the retry is like 3 times by default. Is there a way to set to not do retries?

My code:

```
        ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
        Options opts = new Options();
        opts.setTo(new EndpointReference(strWebServiceUrl));
        opts.setAction(strNameOfMethodToInvoke);
        opts.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(timeOut);
        client.setOptions(opts);
        OMElement res = client.sendReceive(createRequest());
        return (res.toString());
```

---

The code now is

```
        ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
        Options opts = new Options();
        opts.setTo(new EndpointReference(strWebServiceUrl));
        opts.setAction("urn:" + strNameOfMethodToInvoke);
        opts.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(timeOut);

        HttpMethodParams methodParams = new HttpMethodParams();
        DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler retryHandler = new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(0, false);
        methodParams.setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, retryHandler);
        opts.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_METHOD_PARAMS, methodParams);

        client.setOptions(opts);
        OMElement res = client.sendReceive(createRequest());
        return (res.toString());
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you need to add more details, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2211578/edit).  Answers are supposed to be answers, not additional information about the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can set it using the `HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER` parameter. In you case, for example:

```
HttpMethodParams methodParams = new HttpMethodParams();
DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler retryHandler = new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(0, false);
methodParams.setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, retryHandler);
opts.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_METHOD_PARAMS, methodParams);
```

There is a thread on the [wso2.org website](http://wso2.org/forum/thread/3514).

Comment: No! HTTPConstants.HTTP_METHOD_PARAMS don't exist. I try with HTTPConstants.HTTP_METHOD still Retrying.. :(

Comment: Which version of axis2 are you using? Because, HTTPConstants.HTTP_METHOD_PARAMS DOES exist in 1.5 of Axis2.
http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_5/api/org/apache/axis2/transport/http/HTTPConstants.html

Comment: I used Axis2 1.3, now upgraded to 1.5 + dependencies.
But still Retrying .. : (

I add the last code below

Comment: I've debugged it. When it reaches executeWithRetry, it looks up the value of HTTP_METHOD_PARAMS. When I set it up in my Axis2 client code, the param appears in HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(): http.method.retry-handler=org.apache.commons.httpclient.DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler@1eb904d.
It's here: http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethodDirector.java.htm#427
Which version of httpclient do you use? You should have commons-httpclient-3.1.jar.